# Problem importing ESRI shapefile information to MySQL

Tags: qgis, shapefile, mysql

I recently updated to Qgis 2.0 and therefore the "exporttomysql" plugin does not work anymore. What I want to do is exporting the geometry information of a shapefile(Polygon) into a MySQL database. I found some information on how to that at http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=ogr_cheatsheet and adopted their code to fit my needs

```
ogr2ogr -f "MySQL" MYSQL:"CSV_DB,host=myhost,user=user,password=pwd,port=3306" -nln "world" -a_srs "EPSG:4326" ~/Documents/Fields.shp
```

However, I get the error "Unable to open the datasource ~/Documents/Fields.shp with the following drivers....

When I open the file with "ogrinfo" it tells me the the opening with the driver "ESRI Shapefile" was successful. 1; FieldsFinal(Polygon)

Any ideas how I get the data into my database?

Thanks

Comment: Would you please paste in the command string that you used for `ogrinfo`?  I have a feeling that your problem lies with the use of the `~` in the reference to the source shapefile.  Since it worked in one but not the other, I am curious to see if there is a difference in structure.

Comment: Hi commmand ogrinfo ~/Documents/Fields.shp . ~ is a sign used in Unix like operating systems to refer to your home directory. It is translated within the system to the absolute path and should have nothing to do with the problem. In fact ogrinfo takes the command. I am rather suspecting any of the statements used in combination with ogr2ogr such as "-nln". Any other idea on how to get the information into MySQL is also aprectiated.

Comment: Your win path of data source is not exist.  Use the full path.